# Trying to build with boost filesystem: relocation ... can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: apt, c++, cmake, g++, boost

Ubuntu 18.04, boost 1.65, g++ 7.5.0, cmake 3.10.2, GNU make 4.1.  Pretty much everything at the default version for ubuntu 18.04.

I'm trying to port software that uses a number of different boost components to an NVidia Jetson TX2 board... which uses the aforementioned version of ubuntu on it's dev board and host machine.

The hurdle I'm trying to clear at the moment is that linking the first shared lib in cmake: `add_library(<name> SHARED ...)` fails in g++ with the error from the title.  The 'blah blah blah' portion mentions a specific entry point within boost filesystem.

I conclude that I need to rebuild boost filesystem with the requested build flags, `-fPIC`.

Do I need to download the boost source directly and rebuild it, or can I do something with the `apt install`ed -dev boost module[s]?

I'll also need to cross compile them for arm (currently on amd64) so any advice there would be welcome too, but mostly just trying to get boost to link here.

Comment: Can you add some more information: The Ubuntu 18.04: Host or target? Which Linux version/distribution is running on the Jetson? The Boost-Lib you are trying to link: Which version? is it from the target distribution? Are you developing on the target?

Comment: Both target and host are Ubunto 18.04.  I have at least 5 boost libs, but the first one I hit/failed on was FileSystem, v1.65 (which appears to be the most recent version available on 18.04 via `apt-get`.